# Syntax validator

Tags: javascript, syntax, computer-science, interpreter

I have a file stored and I'm reading it with Javascript.
The problem is that I want to simulate a syntactic validator and I can't get a good result.

syntax.txt:

```
class foo {
}
```

The problem is that I can't get the class content. 
What I do is verify if there's a class statement:

```
fileString.match(\^class\g);
```

This returns me: `["class"]`, but I want to get `foo { }` and everething inside.

This is possible?

And what happend if the file changes? something like:
syntax.txt:

```
class foo {
}
class bar {
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: well your reg exp only looks for the class portion...have fun with the  opening and closing } inside of it. It will most likely take more than a reg exp to get the string.

Comment: I'm trying to do it by drawing a directed graph for a finite automaton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to validate a programming language with regex, for the same reason [you can't validate HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). It's not *regular*.

Imagine this (pseudo code):

```
class foo {
    function barbar() {
        if(foobar) {
            case(bar) {
                'x': ... break;
                'y':
                    if(foofoo) {
                        ...
                        return "}";
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll never be able to handle all of the scenarios in regex.  You need a true parser.  You can write your own or use a library, but you definitely cannot rely on regex for this.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I only want to get the text inside the class

Comment: You can't do it.  You can't just search until you hit `}`.  And you can't force a JavaScript regex to count instances of `{` and `}`, or process quotes, or analyze cases when the syntax is just wrong, like a missing `}`.  Regex won't cut it.

Comment: And whats if I say: the class is defined by ´class foo [ ]´ and everithing else uses ´{}´?

Comment: How would that help?  There is nothing out there to keep me from doing something like this inside a JavaScript class: `var x = '{'+"{}{{}"+(function(){ return {x: true};})().x+(y.replace(/[{}]+/,"bar"));`.  This is a perfectly valid (if incoherent) assignment.  Good luck parsing all of the perfectly legitimate uses of `{`,`}`,`[`,`]`,`(`,`)`,`"`,`'`,`/`, etc.